# Using L.BeautifyMarkers with L.MarkerClusters

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want to use markerclusters with custom individual markers using the Leaflet plugin beautify-markers. The markers are customized based on a feature property called EncounterType from a geoJson. When using L.circleMarker the customization worked. Unfortunately, it is not working with the plugin and I think it should since it is not using a png format.

```
    var  brownmarker = {
        icon: 'paw',
        iconShape: 'marker',
        borderColor: '#b3334f',
        textColor: '#b3334f'
        };

    var redmarker = {
        icon: 'bullseye',
        iconShape: 'marker',
        borderColor: 'Red',
        textColor: 'Black',
    };

    var bluemarker = {
        icon: 'camera-retro',
        iconShape: 'marker',
        borderColor: 'Blue',
        textColor: 'Black',
    };

    var Red = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(redmarker);
    var Blue = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(bluemarker);
    var Brown = L.BeautifyIcon.icon(brownmarker);


    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();  
    function style(feature){
        switch (feature.properties.EncounterType) {
            case 'Shooting' ||  'Hunting':
            return {
                Red
            };
            case 'Sighting':
            return {
                Blue
            };
            case 'Attack' || 'livestock' || 'Chased' :
            return {
                Brown
            };
            default:
            return {
                Blue
            }
        }
        }


    var geoJsonLayer= L.geoJSON(storer, {
        pointToLayer: function (geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng);
        },
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            icon: style
        });


    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    map.addLayer(markers);
```

How can I customize these individual markers using this plugin, while keeping them in MarkerCluster form?

Comment: You're marker exist in font awesome and glypicons ? Have you used `iconStyle`. With the doc : `html`property, you can create marker by giving own html. Maybe you should try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issue in using [BeautifyMarker](https://github.com/marslan390/BeautifyMarker) plugin together with [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin.

You just strangely create your marker in `pointToLayer` option.

The `icon` option is for [`L.marker`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#marker) factory, not `L.geoJSON`.

```js
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(storer, {
  pointToLayer: function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
      return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: style(geoJsonPoint)
      });
    }
    /*,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
      icon: style*/
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rbje8v40/

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However when I try it with my code, the clusters begin glitching out and disappear when I zoom in. Am I causing some sort of overload since I have over 100 markers?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing it. You should probably make it a new question and if possible share a live example, e.g. using plunker, jsfiddle, jsbin, etc.